# How to prove $\overline{X}$ is irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

So, I am given this excercise:

Given $a,b$ and $A$, the $k$-algebra  generated by $a,b$ with the relation $a^2=b^3$. Prove that $A$ is not an UFD.

So, I think it all comes down to seeing $A$ as the quotient $B=\frac{k[X,Y]}{<X^2-Y^3>}$. 
So, if $\phi: B \to A$ is an isomorphism, such that $\phi(\overline{X})=a$ and $\phi(\overline{Y})=b$.

Then all I got to do is prove that $\overline{X}$ and $\overline{Y}$ are irreducible, hence $a$ and $b$, hence $a^2=b^3$ is not an unique factorization.

Now I have tried proving that if $\overline{X}=\overline{fg}$, then one of those is inverible, but all I could do is a bunch of calculations that seemed endless and I am pretty sure this is not the way.

What I did was this: if $\overline{X}=\overline{fg}$ then $X-fg=p\cdot(X^2-Y^3)$. For some polynomial $p$.

Now writting $f=f_0+f_1+.....+f_h$, such that $f_i$ is the sum of monomials of degree $i$ (same with $g$).

You can see that either $f_0=0$ or $g_0=0$, lets suppose its $f_0$, and without loss of generality you can suppose $g_0=1$, hence $f_1(X,Y)=X$.

Reasoning like this you can find how $f_0,f_1,f_2,g_0,g_1$ are going to be. (Curious fact: up to $f_2$ all $f_i(X,Y)$are of the form $X\cdot r$,  with some $r\in k[X,Y]$)

This is all I have, and it cannot possibly be just adding relations for the $f_i$'s and $g_j$'s until I find something useful.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

The key to the equations $\overline{X}=\overline{fg}$, $X-fg=p\cdot(X^2-Y^3)$ is to choose f,g with $\deg_X(f),\deg_X(g)<2$ and compare the coefficients ($\in k[Y]$) in $k[Y][X]$.

Comment: Ok, so you are saying, that any polynomial $f$ is equivalent to a polyinomial with degree less than 2? Is this true? I am trying to prove it and it does not seem trivial at all.

Comment: Only the degree in X. This is due to euclidean division.

Comment: Ooo.. That is so clever, I get it. Thanks